# C# Assign role to user if playing game

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to assign a Discord role through bot if specific game being played.

This is my code:

```
    private async Task UserUpdated(SocketGuildUser before, SocketGuildUser after)
    {
        //fetch guild and user by id
        ulong long2 = ulong.Parse(after.Id.ToString());
        var user = _client.GetGuild(myguildid).GetUser(long2);
        var Game = user.Activity as Game;
        if (user.IsBot) { return; }

        //check if playing a game with the name mygamename          
        if (Game.Name == "mygamename")
        {
            //if so, assign the role
            SocketGuild socketGuild = after.Guild;
            SocketRole socketRole = socketGuild.GetRole(myroleid);
            await after.AddRoleAsync(socketRole);
        }
        //Check if user isn't playing game with name mygamename
        else if (Game.Name != "mygamename")
        {
            //If so, remove role
            SocketGuild socketGuild = after.Guild;
            SocketRole socketRole = socketGuild.GetRole(myroleid);
            await after.RemoveRoleAsync(socketRole);
        }
    }
```

However, if I try to play the game with the name mygamename, it assigns the role, but if I stop playing that, it gives me an error in this line:

```
if (Game.Name == "mygamename")
```

It throws me this error:

> 20:31:10 Gateway     A GuildMemberUpdated handler has thrown an
> unhandled exception.: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> myprogram.Program.d__6.MoveNext() in
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\myprogram\myprogram\Program.cs:line 9
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at Discord.EventExtensions.d__2`2.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.d__139.MoveNext()

And it doesn't assign the role. How could I fix that? Is there a better way to fetch before/after and check which game is being played?

Comment: `user.Activity as Game` obviously yields `null`. Is the Activity a Game?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The activity itself is a custom rich presence, but it is displayed as game.

Comment: use the `is` pattern matching to ensure that its a `Game`

Comment: @DanielA.White It gives me "'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Name'"

Comment: If they stop playing the game altogether, won't User.Game be null? In that case you should just remove the if on the else branch

Comment: do `x is Game y`.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Doesn't work either. Still same error.

Comment: `if (user.Activity is Game game && game.Name == "mygamename") { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe casting to `Game` type isn't neccessary? `Game` object, by default, has `ActivityType` property with `Playing` value. So you can just try take first `IActivity`, which has `Playing` activity type and `Name` of your game:

```
var game = userAfter.Activities.FirstOrDefault(activity => activity.Type == ActivityType.Playing
                                                        && activity.Name == "MyGameName");
```

If there won't be any `Playing` activity or not with your game name, `game` variable would be null, so you check it just for `is not null`:

```
private async Task UserUpdated(SocketGuildUser userBefore, SocketGuildUser userAfter)
{
    if (userAfter.IsBot)
        return;

    var myRoleID = 123123123UL;
    var role = userAfter.Guild.GetRole(myRoleID);
    var game = userAfter.Activities.FirstOrDefault(activity => activity.Type == ActivityType.Playing
                                                            && activity.Name == "MyGameName");

    if (game != null)
    {
        // No need to add AddRole, if user already have it
        if (!userAfter.Roles.Contains(role))
            await userAfter.AddRoleAsync(role);
    }
    else
    {
        // No need to call RemoveRole, if user haven't it
        if (userAfter.Roles.Contains(role))
            await userAfter.RemoveRoleAsync(role);
    }         
}
```

Didn't test code example by myself, but you can try anyway.